# Option to choose browser in Python + Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm a beginner in the area of ​​Python + Selenium and I need help with the menu I'm making, I want to make an option to choose the browser that I will use in selenium, but I don't know how to do it.

As shown in the code:

````py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import os

#Menu

print ("**********Choose your browser**********")
print ("")
print ("")

#Navegador

chrome = input ("1 Chrome")
edge = input ("2 Edge")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver")
driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path="msedgedriver")
driver.get("https://outlook.live.com/owa/?nlp=1")```
````

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
browser_select = input("1 Chrome\n2 Edge\n")
if browser_select == "1":
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver")
if browser_select == "2":
    driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path="msedgedriver")

driver.get("https://outlook.live.com/owa/?nlp=1")
```

I have to let you know that this code is weak, if someone enters in the input something different from 1 or 2 the program will crash.
If you want to learn python I suggest you watch some tutorials online, I really like this guy https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sxTmJE4k0ho .

Good luck with your project ;)